# Por que se borra mi ubicacion cada 10 segundos, en androidstudio?

Tags: android-studio, localización

Estoy usando android studio 3.0 y el emulador con android 8.0 y 6.0 para obtener la ubicacion usando el gps del dispositivo.

Problema :
Obtengo la ubicacion desde el emulador , se activa el correspondiente metodo onLocationChanged ,pero cada 10 segundos  este metodo se ejecuta nuevamente sin haber cambiado la posicion en el emulador.

Yo imagino que mi ubicacion se borra y vuelve a tomar como nueva ubicacion la misma posicion cada 10 segundos y por lo tanto tengo un ciclo infinito ejecutandose cada 10 segundos

Este comportamiento es correcto de dicho metodo ?

```
public void GPS() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            latitud = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            longitud = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            System.out.println("................"+latitud+ " ; " +longitud);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
         System.out.println("...........no hay permiso");
        return;
    }
        System.out.println(".............todo ok");
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Es importante agregar el código para poder definir el problema, en este caso me parece que es la configuración de la petición de geolocalización. Revisa [ask]

Comment: edite la pregunta y publique el codigo que como se puede ver es simple y es casi identico al publicado en el sitio de google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa el método [requestLocationUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) de [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

en tu caso tienes definido:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

> `minTime` : intervalo de tiempo mínimo entre actualizaciones de
>   ubicación, en milisegundos
>
> `minDistance` : distancia mínima entre actualizaciones de ubicación,
>   en metros

Por lo tanto, posiblemente en el emulador trata de obtener una posición lo más rápido posible, incluso en producción debes definir valores adecuados para evitar consumo de tu batería.

Te sugiero configures estos valores, por ejemplo que pida la nueva posición cada minuto (60000 milisegundos) y cuando exista un cambio en la posición de 5 metros.

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, locListener, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: es que mi intencion es que obtenga la posicion lo mas rapido posible. lo que me parece raro es que ya use este codigo con androidstudio 2.3 y no recuerdo que realizara esta accion del metodo de ejecutarse cada 10 segundos aun sin cambiar la posicion

Comment: Hice tu recomendacion y ahora si solamente se ejecuta una sola vez el metodo. Lo que me hace pensar que al cambiar los valores de tiempo minimo y distancia actuan como un && logico y al ser cumplirse ambos entonces entra al metodo.